# Neo4j query works fine in browser but not in Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I was trying to execute the following query in Neo4j. In the Desktop Client it works fine, but when I use Spring Data Neo4j it returns nothing.

```
MATCH (u1:Users)-[:WATCHED]->(m3:Movies)
WHERE u1.userId =4
WITH [i in m3.movieId | i] as movies
MATCH path = (u:Users)-[:WATCHED]->(m1:Movies)-[s:SIMILAR]->(m2:Movies),
(m2)-[:GENRES]->(g:Genres),
(u)-[:FAVORITE]->(g)
WHERE u.userId =4 and not m2.movieId in movies
RETURN distinct u.userId as userId, g.genres as genres, 
m2.title as title, m2.rating_mean as rating
ORDER BY m2.rating_mean descending
LIMIT 5
```

Here is my method in the repository interface:

```
@Query("MATCH (u1:Users)-[:WATCHED]->(m3:Movies) " + 
        "WHERE u1.userId ={userId} " + 
        "WITH [i in m3.movieId | i] as movies " + 
        "MATCH path = (u:Users)-[:WATCHED]->(m1:Movies)-[s:SIMILAR]->(m2:Movies), " + 
        "(m2)-[:GENRES]->(g:Genres), " + 
        "(u)-[:FAVORITE]->(g) " + 
        "WHERE u.userId ={userId} and not m2.movieId in movies " + 
        "RETURN distinct u.userId as userId, g.genres as genres,  " + 
        "m2.title as title, m2.rating_mean as rating " + 
        "ORDER BY m2.rating_mean descending " + 
        "LIMIT 5")
Collection<Movie> recommendForUser(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

Even if I switch the userId parameter to 4, it returns nothing.

Entities:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
@NodeEntity("Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long userId;

    @Relationship(type = "WATCHED")
    private Set<UsersMovies> usersMovies;

    @Relationship(type = "FAVORITE")
    private Set<UsersGenres> usersGenres;

    public User(Long userId) {
        super();
        this.userId = userId;
    }
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
@NodeEntity("Movies")
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long movieId;

    private String title;

    @Property(name = "rating_mean")
    private Float ratingMean;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Relationship(type = "GENRES")
    private Set<MoviesGenres> moviesGenres;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Relationship(type = "SIMILAR")
    private Set<MoviesSimilarity> moviesSimilarity;

}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
@NodeEntity("Genres")
public class Genre {

    @Id
    private String genres;
}
```

I'm using Neo4j 3.5.12 and Spring version 2.2.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because your query returns no movies. 
Instead of a bunch of properties

```
RETURN distinct u.userId as userId, g.genres as genres,
m2.title as title, m2.rating_mean as rating
```

try returning the Movie nodes themselves, to be able to map onto your return type of `Collection<Movie>`

```
RETURN m2
```